# how to add Json header in json array parsed from Java Object

Tags: java, android, json

i found many examples to parse java object to Json.
Thanks for that.But i have one issue, i want Json in following format

```
{
  "parent":
  {
    "sub-parent-1":
    {
      "child-1": 1,
      "child-2": 2
    },
    "sub-parent-2":
    {
      "child-2": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible with java.
Please answer.Thanks in advanced..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create Current Json String as in Java :

```
    JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject subparentone = new JSONObject();

    JSONObject subparenttwo = new JSONObject();

    subparentone.put("child-1", "1");
    subparentone.put("child-2", "2");

    subparenttwo.put("child-2", "3");

    parent.put("sub-parent-1", subparentone);
    parent.put("sub-parent-2", subparenttwo);

   JSONObject finalparent = new JSONObject();
   finalparent.put("parent", parent);
```

and finalparent JsonObject output as:

```
{
  "parent": {
    "sub-parent-1": {
      "child-1": 1,
      "child-2": 2
    },
    "sub-parent-2": {
      "child-2": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.Is the same possible with Gson?

Comment: @PrathameshTalathi : i never used Gson but it's also possible using Gson .

Comment: is there any link for ref for me.i am also new to Gson.

Comment: @PrathameshTalathi : you can see [this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples) Gson API but my preference is use android default `JsonParser` is better from any other third party lab until you have specific requirement

Comment: Thanks i got solution with Gson also

Comment: @PrathameshTalathi  : most welcome friend :) if this answer help you in solving your issue then you can mark it as answer.Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21557/discussion-between-prathamesh-talathi-and--k)

Answer (score 0):

I have created class for parent and pass child to it. And convert that parent class into Json using Gson.